# docker-proxy using port when no containers are running

Tags: ubuntu, docker

On a ubunty 1404 machine, docker-proxy is using port 6379, however there are no docker containers running.

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep docker    
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      28438/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN      28266/dockerd
$ docker ps -all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS       PORTS               NAMES
$
```

After I stop docker service, this process is gone, and that port is available, however when I start docker back up, docker-proxy is still using that port even though there are no docker containers running.

```
$ docker info
## Output:
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-38-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 31.32 GiB
Name: xxxxx
ID: LILE:5WFT:2EPL:OXCN:GZG7:C4WE:AFCX:LNAT:TBMG:XQFP:QX7W:XLYK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try:

`sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -f /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db`

From this [ticket](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277).

Comment: That only broke it further to me: `Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container traefik: network ba038962a399146089185971cf10cd11920406b3b4abeed739186db8c9cc865c not found
`

Comment: And, naturally, sudo service docker start

Comment: Not working for me. Ports are still blocked.

Comment: This was the single thing that worked for me... Things that did not work (even when combined): docker service restart, docker system prune --volumes, killing the processes manually, ... you name it, nothing worked. Couldn't run devcontainer because the ports were always blocked. Nice Docker bug...

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me on Linux, and without having to delete any resources.

```sh
# Stop docker
sudo service docker stop

# Find your particular zombie proxy processes
sudo netstat -pna | grep docker-proxy
# tcp6       0      0 :::8025       :::*     LISTEN      <PID_A>/docker-proxy  
# tcp6       0      0 :::13306      :::*     LISTEN      <PID_B>/docker-proxy
# ...

# Kill them
sudo kill -9 PID_A PID_B ...

# restart
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be because of unused networks.
Instead of deleting the local-kv.db file, try the following command:

```
docker network prune
```

See [docker network prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I uninstalled Docker with apt, but turns out I have another version of Docker installed with snap.

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

Comment: Also had to reboot my system after that.

Answer (score 0):

On my case(using Ubuntu20.04) a docker-container was "on" even using docker-compose down. So it was using the port that i needed to use in my case was 80/tcp port.

What worked for me:

1. sudo ss -tulpn
2. sudo kill + pid tha was o port that i needed to use.
3. docker-compose up -d

Only with this steps the problem was solved, i dont know why, it could be a bug or something with changing the ports and starting a new container solved it. But it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is about `when no docker containers are running`, in general case, the first thing is to check with

```
docker ps
```

the currently running containers.

Docker may automatically start containers after a reboot if `docker-compose start` was once executed and `docker-compose stop` was not properly done.